# Compilation error "cannot call member function without object"

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a GUI for an already created C program (an image scraper). The image scraper works but I am trying to implement the GUI which allows a user to input a website to scrape images from into a line edit box (lineEdit), and then on click of a push button (pushButton) it takes the input text from the line edit box and uses it as the argument to run the C program in the background. Except I can't get that far because of the issue mentioned above.

Below is my code, the header and main files haven't been changed, and any changes that have been made have been done through the GUI designer over manual changes.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

char *arguments;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString program = "~/Desktop/IS";
    QString arguments = QLineEdit::text(); //error on this line

    QProcess *myProcess = newQProcess(parent);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);

}
```

Comment: In general you should also post a copy/paste of the error message; little things like error numbers or line number can be helpful.  Anyway, the problem is that `QLineEdit::text()` needs an instance of a `QLineEdit` object to be called against.  Presumably there's one in your `MainWindow` class that you want to use.

Comment: Well, have you implemented those methods that it complains it can't find? You declared them as slots, you better implement them. Sure you didn't "edit" that file, that doesn't mean the file is wrong. You're wrong if you *declare* slots that you never *define*. If you don't need those slots, simply remove their declarations.

Comment: It seemed to add them for no reason, i don't remember adding any other functions other than onclicked, but anyway. Thank you very much, my problem is now solved :) It's not working as intended.. but it runs now and i can work from there. Thank you very much!

Comment: What seemed to add them where? You are the one who writes the header file *and* the .ui file, and the slots were there declared there: either in the header, or in the .ui file. Do *not* modify the moc-generated file (in case you "fixed" it by modifying that file).

Comment: I deleted them from both and no issues so far. Anyway, One final question. I'm trying to replace QString program = QDir::homePath() + "/Desktop/IS"; with the directory the application is in, currently home/dan/desktop/imagescraper + "/IS", but if i moved it to documents i'd want it to realise it's location home/dan/documents/imagescraper automatically. I've tried QDir::current() and QApplication::ApplicationDirPath() but they don't work (unless i'm doing something wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All errors are in `on_pushButton_clicked()`.

1. A space is missing between `new` and `QProcess`.
2. There's no `parent` variable in scope. There is, of course, a `parent()` member of `QObject`. You can simply parent the process to the window itself.
3. You can't call `QLineEdit::text` without an object, as the error says. Only *you* know what object you need. Let's pretend for now that the object is `ui->myLineEdit`.
4. The tilde expansion is done by the shell. The kernel has no idea what a tilde is, neither does a `QProcess`. You need to provide full path to the executable.
5. The home directory is not always available from the `HOME` environment variable either. It should be obtained from the portable `QDir::homePath()`.
6. `QProcess::start()` does not take two strings. It needs a *list* of strings as the second parameter. Since you only intend to provide one argument, it's a simple matter to wrap it up in a string list.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QString program = QDir::homePath() + "/Desktop/IS";
   QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
   myProcess->start(program, QStringList(ui->myLineEdit->text()));
   // The variant above is slightly shorter then the equivalent line below:
   myProcess->start(program, QStringList() << ui->myLineEdit->text());
}
```

Comment: @Spratters53 "The only thing i can think of with "no matching function" is that it's finding the program but not the argument to input" The error is given by the compiler, not by the running program. The compiler complains that your program, as written, is invalid. The compiler doesn't even try to find your "program", since it doesn't execute your code. The "finding of the program" is done by `QProcess::start` *when it actually executes*. You might be confused if you come from a scripting language background, where "compilation" and execution are intermingled.

Comment: It is only supposed to be a single address at once, just a copy paste and run affair, never more than one. I did not realise you could call the QStringList() straight as the argument! the official docs don't mention anything like that. Now that makes a lot more sense. And it solves the issues, although apparently i'm missing the -lGL file now so not all is solved yet, but thanks very much for your help

Comment: @Spratters53 The docs don't need to explain it, since it's inherent from the design of the C++ language. You create a temporary object, append to it, and pass it in as an argument. You can also create a single-entry string list by using the `QStringList(const QString&)` argument.

Answer (score 0):

On your MainWindow Form just create a lineEdit somewhere called 'InputWebSite'

and then replace

```
 QString arguments = QLineEdit::text();
```

With

```
QString arguments = ui->InputWebSite->text();
```